# How does using variables in javascript work?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, meter

I have some simple code here, and I want to test it out, by making the display none, is there something wrong with my javascript? (I'm very new to js)

```js
 var meter = document.getElementById("meter").innerHTML;
        meter.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<meter id="meter" min="0" max="10"></meter>
```

The console says meter is undefined, but I defined it right above.

Comment: `.innerHTML` retrieves the string content of the element. Change the *element itself* instead.

Comment: "_The console says meter is undefined_" No, that is not what it says.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`meter` is the `innerHTML` of the element (which is a string), not the element itself.

Instead, use:

```js
var meter = document.getElementById("meter");
meter.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<meter id="meter" min="0" max="10"></meter>
```

If you want to hide it and get its value, you can do:

```js
var meter = document.getElementById("meter");
meter.style.display = "none";
var val = meter.value;
console.log(val)
```

```html
<meter id="meter" min="0" max="10" value="3"></meter>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand variable types, but when I do it directly, like `document.getElementById("meter").style.display = "none";` I just realized it has no innerHTML.

Comment: @Proking73Questioneer Why are you trying to get the `innerHTML` of a `meter` tag? Do you want to get the value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: @Spectric Yes, I was going to animate it so it goes 1-10, but I used display as an test.